# Azure: Is it necessary to have dedicated Private DNS for each resource type like file, blob, table, Cosmos, and SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-private-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

My application on Azure consists of a Storage Account, Cosmos DB, SQL Server, a Web App, and a Function App. The Private Endpoint needs to be set up and used. Every type of Private Endpoint requires a dedicated Azure Private DNS.

**eg:**

- privatelink.documents.azure.com
- privatelink.file.core.windows.net

Is it necessary to have dedicated Private DNS for each resource type like file, blob, table, Cosmos, and SQL? Can't I use the same Private DNS for all type of Private Endpoints?

Comment: You need to have separate zones unfortunately for each privatelink.* zone. :-( You only need them once though since you can link the same zone against VNets in any region and subscription… but yes, each type needs a separate one, like you wrote…

Comment: @holger, can you post it as an answer? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary and you will need a separate Private DNS Zone per resource type.

See [Azure services DNS zone configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns) for details.

However, you can re-use the same zone across regions and subscriptions, so you should only need them once within your Azure tenant.